# Ruby 1.9.1 and Jrails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jrails

I'm getting error:

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptElementProxy::ActionView
```

I've tried forcing a reinstall of jrails which didn't fix the error, and Googling the error has yet to yeild a result. Any suggestions? Ruby 1.9.1, Rails 2.3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028766/rescue-in-constmissing-error-with-ruby-1-9-1-rails-2-3-2-and-jrails-0-4), jrails has apparently been patched to work with Ruby 1.9.

The latest version is available on [github](http://github.com/cheald/jrails).

*Alternative link:* http://github.com/aaronchi/jrails

Comment: "I've tried forcing a reinstall of jrails which didn't fix the error" 

 I'm still getting the same error. Since everyone's answer is to re-install (yes, i'm using the latest version on github), and that doesn't seem to work for me, i may have no choice but to go to install a different version of ruby...sigh.

Answer (score 3):

Reinstall it using the latest version on github:

```
./script/plugin install git://github.com/aaronchi/jrails.git --force
```